# FTP client in java to upload file sometimes shows error

Tags: java, connection, ftp-client

HI Friends I am working on a java application to store the file into the server 
but when i upload some file its shows

```
org.apache.commons.net.io.CopyStreamException: IOException caught while copying.
QUIT
550 can't access file.
```

can any body tell me how to solve that?

```
public void uploadtxtFile(String localFileFullName, String fileName, String hostDir)
            throws Exception {
            FTPClient ftpclient= DBConnection.connect();
        File file = new File(localFileFullName);
        if (!(file.isDirectory())) {
            if (file.exists()) {
                FileInputStream input = null;
                 BufferedInputStream bis=null;
               try {
                    input = new FileInputStream(new File(localFileFullName));
                    if (input != null) {

                        hostDir = hostDir.replaceAll("//", "/");
                       logger.info("uploading host dir : " + hostDir);
                     boolean bool =false ;
                       logger.error("Replay of the ftp store file is 1111"+  ftpclient.getReplyCode());
                 try{
                     ftpclient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                       logger.error("Replay of the ftp store file is 2222"+  ftpclient.getReplyCode());
                   if(  ftpclient.isConnected()){                   
                    //  here server timeout error is get
                       logger.error("here server timeout error is get");//new
                       bis = new BufferedInputStream(input);
                       logger.error("Replay of the ftp store file is 3333"+  ftpclient.getReplyCode());
                       bool =  ftpclient.storeFile(hostDir, bis);

                   }  else{
                       logger.error("here server timeout error is get");//new
                             bis = new BufferedInputStream(input);
                       logger.error("Replay of the ftp store file is 6666"+  ftpclient.getReplyCode());
                       ftpclient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                       bool =  ftpclient.storeFile(hostDir, bis);
                   }}finally{
                       bis.close();
                    input.close();
                     }

                   logger.error("Replay of the ftp store file is 4444 "+  ftpclient.getReplyCode());
                            if (bool) {
                            logger.info("Success uploading file on host dir :"+hostDir);
                        } else {
                             logger.error("file  not uploaded.");

                        }

                    } else {
                         logger.error("uploading file input null.");
             }
                } catch(Exception ex)
                {
                     logger.error("Error in connection ="+ex);


                }finally {
                 ftpclient.logout();
                     ftpclient.disconnect();

             }

            } else {
                  logger.info("uploading file is not exists.");
            }
        }
    }
```

and also the response of file folder is not show

Comment: Those file have access permission for login user who using Java?

Comment: i can not understand what u ask please clear that

Comment: If I  am upload number of file some file is upload but one or two of them is   show that exception if i give any permission to access that. so every file is show same exception

Comment: This is a client, not a server. `input` canot possibly be null at the point you are testing it. What sort of a `DBConnection` class is it that returns an `FTPClient`?

Comment: yes DBConnection class FTPClient

Answer (score 1):

SYMPTOMS

When attempting to upload a file to a remote FTP site, a 550 error code is encountered, resulting in an error message similar to one of the following examples:

**Example 1:**

```
STATUS:> Transferring file "/pub/yourfile.txt"...

COMMAND:> SIZE yourfile.txt

550 yourfile.txt: No such file.

STATUS:>   Requested action not taken (e.g., file or directory not found, no access).

COMMAND:> CWD /pub/yourfile.txt

550 /pub/yourfile.txt: No such file or folder.

STATUS:>   Requested action not taken (e.g., file or directory not found, no access).

COMMAND:> STOR yourfile.txt
```

**Example 2:**

```
COMMAND:> STOR yourfile.txt

550 Permission Denied.

ERROR:> Requested action not taken (e.g., file or directory not found, no access).
```

**CAUSE**

**Example 1:**

In this example the 550 code returned by the remote FTP server is for
information purposes only.  It is not an error and should be ignored
by the user.  In this case an upload command has already been given
but before the upload can be started CuteFTP needs it determine
whether or not the file being transferred already exists on the remote
site as either a file or a folder.

First, the SIZE command is sent in an attempt to determine if a file with the same name exists on the remote site.  The server
 responds with a 550 indicating that the file does not already exist
there.

Next, the CWD command is sent in an attempt to determine if a folder with the same name exists on the remote site.  The server
responds with a 550 indicating that a folder by that name does not
 exist.

Finally, the STOR command is given and the file upload begins.

**Example 2:**

A file upload is being attempted but the remote server has denied the
 needed permission.  The 550 error code is a result of insufficient
 account privileges on the remote FTP server.  The error is not caused
 by CuteFTP.

**RESOLUTION**

**Example 1:**

Not applicable.  In this example the 550 code returned by the remote
 FTP server is for information purposes only.  It is not an error and
 should be ignored by the user.

**Example 2:**

If you believe that your FTP account privileges or permissions are
configured incorrectly, contact the technical support department at
 the remote FTP site or your Web hosting company for help.

Or you can check  [FTP "550 Access is denied" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369571/ftp-550-access-is-denied-error)

Comment: Don't use quote formatting for text that isn't quoted.

Comment: i under stand what u say but  can you tell me connection is not open exception is come because i the above exception is not come then am send a number of file but when i am sending 20-30 file they show connecton is not open if there is no connection so how can send 20-30 file  and if it is not open so after the next file it didnt show any exception

Comment: It may be possible connection is going down when doing multiple upload/download